# Как сделать выполнение кода при загрузке страницы, а не только при событии?

Tags: javascript

У меня такой код, когда выбираю один из элементов `select`, показывает или скрывает ниже представленных блоков:

```js
function Selected(a) {
  var label = a.value;
  if (label == 1) {
    document.getElementById("Block1").style.display = 'block';
  } else if (label == 2) {
    document.getElementById("Block1").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="actSelect" class="Validate_Required " name="actSelect" aria-required="true" onChange="Selected(this)">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
  <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
  <option value="2">Пункт 2</option>
  <option value="3">Пункт 3</option>
</select>


<div id='Block1' style='display: none;'>
  Пункт 1
</div>

<div id='Block2' style='display: none;'>
  Пункт 2
</div>

<div id='Block3' style='display: none;'>
  Пункт 3
</div>
```

Никак не могу сделать тоже самое при загрузке страницы. Допустим Пункт 2 `selected` ( `<option value="2" selected>Пункт 2</option>`), как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке страницы работал *js* код (`else if (label==2)` )?

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы заставить выполнить событие принудительно без "дотрагивания" до селекта, достаточно вызвать его `.onchange();`

```js
function Selected(a) {
    var label = a.value;
  
    if (label == 1) {
        document.getElementById("Block1").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("Block2").style.display = 'none';
    } else if (label == 2) {
        document.getElementById("Block1").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("Block2").style.display = 'block'; // Для теста
    }
}

function onDocumentReady() {
    document.querySelectorAll('#actSelect option').forEach((item) => {  
      if (item.value == 2)
          item.selected = 'selected';
    });

    document.querySelector('#actSelect').onchange();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDocumentReady);
```

```html
<select id="actSelect" class="Validate_Required " name="actSelect" aria-required="true" onChange="Selected(this)">
  <option value="">-</option>
  <option value="1">Пункт 1</option>
  <option value="2">Пункт 2</option>
  <option value="3">Пункт 3</option>
</select>


<div id='Block1' style='display: none;'>
  Пункт 1
</div>

<div id='Block2' style='display: none;'>
  Пункт 2
</div>

<div id='Block3' style='display: none;'>
  Пункт 3
</div>
```

Comment: Алексей спасибо огромное Вы мне помагли)